# Suppose that for all $t <1$ there are points $x_t$ and $y_t$ such that $d(x_t,y_t) = t$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose that for all $t <1$ there are points $x_t$ and $y_t$ such that $d(x_t,y_t) = t$. Prove that there exists points $x$ and $y$ such that $d(x,y) = 1$.

I have attempted to use the fact that since $A= \{(x_t,y_t) : d(xt,yt)=t\}$ is infinite then $A$ has a limit point since $X$ is compact and then the limit point would be this set $\{(x,y) : d(x,y) =1\}$... but i dont even know if im looking at this in the right way.

Comment: Hint: In a compact metric space, every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Why does the function $X\times X\to \mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto \left|1-d(x,y)\right|$ assume its minimum?

Comment: By Tychonoff's theorem, we know that $X \times X$ is compact. Since the function $f: X \times X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ with $(x,y) \mapsto |1-d(x,y)|$ is continuous, the image of $X \times X$ also needs to be compact. However, if $0$ is not in the image, then $f(X \times X) = (0,1]$ which is not compact. A contradiction, so $0 \in f(X \times X)$ right?